# webpackDevServer continuously console: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3003/ws' failed

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'd config and start my local webpackDevServer-based react project, it shows well on browser page ,but when I opened my dev-tools ,it just continuously console out the below errors, apparently,webpackDevServer is disconnect and reconnect again and again.

WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3003/ws' failed:
[webpack-dev-server] Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
[console error info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjxvq.jpg)

> And my local config info is as below.

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
  devServer:{
    port: 3003
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Development',
      template: paths.appHtml
    }),
  ]
};
```

**start.js**

```
"use strict";

const Webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpackConfig = require("../config/webpack.config.dev");

const compiler = Webpack(webpackConfig);
const devServerOptions = { ...webpackConfig.devServer, open: true };
const server = new WebpackDevServer(devServerOptions, compiler);

server.startCallback(() => {
  console.log('Successfully started server on http://localhost:3003');
});
```

**package.json->scripts**

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js",
    "start": "node ./scripts/start.js"
  }
```

I'd config the devServer port as 3003 aleady.

could any guys please give me some instructions how to solve this issue? Really looking forward to your answer!

Comment: I construct and config the project manually, not by create-react-app tool

Answer (score 3):

Try to configure the [devServer.host](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost) properly. This worked for my case.

```js
  devServer: {
    port: 3003,
    host: "127.0.0.1"  // <-- this
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

try in production mode:

```
devServer: {
  webSocketServer: false,
}
```

worked for me

Comment: Where does this config go?